# Compile only specific library from Qt

Tags: c++, qt, configure

I want to compile one of Qt's default libraries (QDeclarative) on OSX.

Which argument do I need to pass to ./configure to achieve this?

Comment: ./configure is for generating build description files, once you have those you can choose which parts you want to compile. On linux you would do `make module-qtdeclarative`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a standalone component as far as I know it is dependent on QtXML and some other parts of QT within QtCore. Just compile QT for Mac using the cross platform options in the link Evan Teran posted here.

If you only want to link against QtCore add `QT -= gui` to your .pro file in QtCreator or otherwise specify removal of the default included QtGui in your linking command line.

Answer (score 3):

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/configure-options.html. it's more of a black list then a whitelist. For example, if you wanted to build it **without** webkit support, you would run:

```
./configure -no-webkit
```

Though it looks like most of the blacklist options are for windows only, you may be slightly out of luck :-/.

Comment: I know these and also pass arguments like -no-webkit and -release already but there must be a way to only compile certain libraries (or all) but not the demos etc.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, as of 09'15 and in case of Qt 5.5, excluding modules is described in [the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/configure-options.html#excluding-a-qt-submodule) as the following:

```
./configure -skip qtconnectivity
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows anyway, if you are selective about which submodules you initialize and update, when you run configure, only those submodules will be built. This is a way to whitelisit only the modules you really need. I would hope this works just as well on the other OSs...

```
>> git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git
>> cd qt5
>> git checkout 5.15
>> git submodule init qtbase
>> git submodule update qtbase
>> configure -nomake tests -nomake examples -opensource
>> nmake
```